# How can find functions or methods library in Code Blocks

Tags: c++, function, codeblocks

I cannot find the library of available functions.  For example, I can find the `pow()` function by pressing the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> keys in Turbo C++ and the result is *math.h*.

How can I find the methods library in Code Blocks?

Answer (score 0):

How about using C++ plugin, CDT. It provides very nice intellisense for C++. I used to use codeblocks and moved to Eclipse now. The reason was it was unclear to read the codes most of the times. You can download CDT from [this link.](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/)

Comment: Personally I prefer the code completion and general functionality of [Qt Creator](https://download.qt-project.org/official_releases/qtcreator/) which works fine with any C++ project using CMake, QMake etc.

Comment: That's fantastic that you like Eclipse CDT, but it would be counterproductive to answer every Code::Blocks question with "Download Eclipse instead!".  Please refrain from doing so.